# Does Lord Krishna approve propagation of the Gita worldwide?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

In the Gita, Sri Krishna orders Arjuna :

> 18.67 This (Gita) you should **NEVER teach to one who is devoid of austerities, NOR to one who is not a devotee. Also, NEITHER to one who does not render service to Me, NOR to one who has any dislike for Me.**

In the very next sloka, He says

> 18.68 He who, entertaining supreme devotion to Me, will speak of this highest secret, **to My devotees** will without doubt reach Me alone.

In these days, Gita is being propagated with great enthusiasm across the globe.

Does Sri Krishna allow this in any scripture?

Comment: We have gone down cheap so that at least through this lets see if humans change :)

Comment: There are some secrets coming out today more than ever...Lord said in Gita like that but he could also have chosen persons in current time to carry out tasks for world. We cannot know his leela.

Comment: @sv. For example, Gitamahatmya is not a part of Gita

Comment: Doesn't he mean that Arjuna should not teach it to anyone as compared to a common saint?

Comment: @user1952500 Arjuna is just a representative here.Arjuna neither compiled Gita nor is known to give spiritual lesson to anyone.

Comment: @commonman yes, so he followed the order :)

Comment: The answer to your question is no, there are no scriptural references where Krishna relaxes the reqirements for discipleship. How do I know for shure, I have all the Holy Texts of India memorized.

Comment: @WilliamHird what happened to your answer?

Comment: since Gita is conversation between Krishna & Arjuna, maybe his advice was for Arjuna only :) Only he is not supposed to teach others without checking.. no restrictions for others listening/teaching Gita.. heh

Answer (score 3):

Trying to explain the knowledge of the B.Gita among the listed  people has  been restricted by Krishna, probably to save the time and endeavor of His devotees.

Nevertheless, in the following two verses [18.70](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-70/) & [18.71](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/18/71) (with authoritative commentaries), He is also blessing His non-devotees with the freedom to study and learn the scripture.

> > अध्येष्यते **च** **य** इमं धर्म्यं संवादमावयो:|
> >     ज्ञानयज्ञेन तेनाहमिष्ट: स्यामिति मे मति:||७०||
> >
> > **And** I declare that the one **who** studies this divine discourse of ours worships Me by his/her intelligence.**(18.70)**
> >
> > श्रद्धावाननसूय: **च** श्रृणुयादपि **योनरः***|
> >
> > सोऽपिमुक्तःशुभाँल्लोकान्प्राप्नुयात्पुण्यकर्मणाम्||७१||
> >
> > **And** anyone **who** listens with faith and without envy becomes free from sinful reactions and attains to the auspicious realm where the pious dwell.**(18.71)**

Here **"who"** **("य")** doesn't mean only a devotee but anyone thirsty of divine knowledge can study and participate in the supreme jnana-yajna **(worshiping Him by knowing Him).**

The propagation of knowledge of the B.Gita is as per Krishna's declared wish. So that each and all can study Gita and understand the knowledge. All those, who have been confused reading different types of literature about the scripture.

> **N.B.** The Sanskrit phrase **"य"** from root **"यत्"** indicates **"whoever"**, in a gender neutral sense. (Not to be confused with sanskrit neuter gender word, however, the singular masculine gender phrase is **"यः"** and feminine gender will be **"या"** in the same case form of the Sanskrit "shabda-roop", "ek-vachan" and "prathama-vibhakti").
>
> ***योनरः = यः + नरः**("sandhi-vichchhed").
>
> The invariable (connective) term **"च"** refers to **"and"**, in the appending notion.

Some references available online:

1)https://www.quora.com/What%E2%80%99s-the-best-way-to-read-the-Bhagavad-Gita-for-comprehension

2)https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/18/verse/70

3)http://www.yugalsarkar.com/bhagwad-gita-chapter-18-shlok-70-sanskrit-translation

4)https://www.narayanashramatapovanam.org/bg-ebook/2339-bhagavad-gita-chap-18-verse-70

5)https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-71/

6)https://www.onelittleangel.com/sacred/books/bhagavad-gita.asp?mc=18&p=1&chap=1

7)https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?htrskd=1&httyn=1&htshg=1&scsh=1&choose=1&&language=dv&field_chapter_value=18&field_nsutra_value=71

8)https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/18/70

9)https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagavad_Gita

10)https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanskrit

Comment: No, Not to anyone.He restricts it only for His devotees. So He did not contradict this sloka or provide any extra freedom.In this sloka He says not to preach it to non-devotees and in the next sloka encourages to preach to the devotees.Attaining devotion is not easy and He therefore prohibits preaching of the Gita to the common masses across the globe.

Comment: study don't just read !! Krishna

Comment: Yes I have studied.Thanks

Comment: ok. have ever visit the nearest krishna temple and find the all colourful devotees of Krishna there, from all across the globe !!                 if Krishna's knowledge had been restricted propagation we could never  find those all colorful devotees today in Vrindavan (India) and/or in New Vrindavan (the USA) or anyother locations across the globe.

Comment: To me what Krishna said is important, not the colourful devotee.Hinduism does not believe in conversion.These colourful devotees would have reached nearer to God by practising their religion God had provided them with.Temples are not places to see colourful people btw.

Comment: to you only for sure  !! He says studying of B.Gita is more important than trying to explain the knowledge (whatsoever grasped) to everyone out there. :)

Comment: I fully agree with you.Those who preach Gita would have done more benefit to themselves and to the world if they concentrated on studying the Gita themselves instead of preaching it.

Comment: yes. that is the reason He restricted, He is the Almighty, He is knowing all the future. He is so mercyful to His non believers, otherwise, there have been many who would have no reasons killing masses for not accepting their knowledge and believe as per the propagation of their self-styled philosophy of peace.

Comment: the desire to know krishna confirms him or her as Krishna's one of the four types of devotees, i.e. "jijnayasu" (artah, jijnayasu, artharthi, jnani). He never contradicts, however, studying His knowledge paves the very path for His devotion system.

Comment: No, jijnasu is a sanskrit word and has deeper meaning than inquisitiveness.

Comment: jijnasu means what ??

Comment: Please refer to commentaries of the different ancient acharyas who wrote commentaries on the Gita, Searching the internet or reading a book out of inquisitiveness and studying the scripture to know about God are completely different.'Jijana' is a term used in the Brahma-Sutra also.

Comment: "athato brahmajijnasa" is the first sutra (code) of the vedanta. Nevertheless, first we have to know Krishna is know as Brahman too. Brahman is however, is His form which is also known as His Supreme Unknown kingdom (or God's kingdom). Which has all the qualities of krishna but all are never revealed and manifested. The knowers are not the devotees of krishna. That's why Braham knower are known as jnani. Which are considered to be on the difficult path of devotion in chapter# 12. By the way, Parmatama is also His form and the worshipper of Krishna's this form is known as a Yogi.

Comment: The Yogi who wants to unite with Parmatama form of krishna. Both the jnani and yogi are destined to liberation or moxa, either of the five kinds. However the devotee or bhakta in worst situation is granted Salokya-mukti (same planet of vishnu, vaikuntha and polestar/dhruva planet, the other moxa/liberations,however, are enemies for the devotees) which is not granted either to the jnani or the yogi. The higher devotees get krishna's own planets, among these planets, golok, is the apex domain. The true "jijnasu" means the devotee, whoever has a descending desire to know more and more about Krsna

Comment: @sv.  please don't edit or interfere in the independent answers, if permission granted or not. Always try to post answers on your own. And please do follow the basic ethics of the Internet society.

Comment: You need to credit the Author whose translation you are quoting. Else it would be considered as plagiarism.

Comment: ok. ok. the tanslation is as per Gita press and Iskcon bbt. please refer the text therein.

Comment: we think stackexchange is not a platform to promote personal ideas/links or websites. please don't be personal, be social and give credit to the community network, the Internet. best regards.

Comment: we don't want to share the credit of editing (without suggestions), rather, we wish to promote more and more independent answers at stackexchange. Be confident, and post answer on your own and have a full credit of posts.

Comment: @TheDestroyer tell us the original author of Bh.Gita.

Comment: Tulsi Pandit has mentioned jijnasa (desire for knowledge about God)  in Uttar-kand as very important ingredient of devotion: "janehi binu na hohahi partiti, binu partiti na hohahi preeti. binu preeti nahi bhakti dridahahi, jimi khagpati jal ke chiknai." -Garud-Kakbhusundi samvad.

Answer (score 2):

The statement of Sri Krishna in the sloka quoted, is **very subtle in nature**.

> इदं ते नातपस्काय नाभक्ताय कदाचन।
>
> न चाशुश्रूषवे वाच्यं न च मां योऽभ्यसूयति।।18.67।।
>
> This [knowledge]  should never be imparted to one who does not observe **austerities**; to him who has no **devotion**; to him who has **no desire to listen**; and to him who is **indignant** towards Me.

---

The words/phrases austerities, devotion, no desire to listen, indignant used in the meaning of the sloka in question, can be interpreted in a different manner also.

These can be applied not only to devotees of Sri Krishna , but  to **devotees of other gods, jnanis and duty minded persons** as well.

**Sri Krishna himself taught Arjuna about Karma Yoga (कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेषु कदाचन। - BG 2.47)**

A devotee/jnani/karma yogi or an atheist, whoever follow austerities for self discipline,  will be devoted to their work also.  In fact karma yogis/atheists have more practical bent of mind.

So this sloka refers to all the persons, who have commitment towards his work, have a self discipline.  Further, it is easier to make a person with commitment towards work, understand subtle spiritual aspects.

### However, we can never teach spiritual concepts to persons, who feign devotion towards the God, but have no commitment in achieving his goal.

By the way,  as **@user30612** rightly pointed out in his/her answer, the sloka in 18.70 allows studying of Gita by anyone.

> अध्येष्यते च य इमं धर्म्यं संवादमावयोः।
>
> ज्ञानयज्ञेन तेनाहमिष्टः स्यामिति मे मतिः।।18.70।।
>
> And he who will study this sacred conversation between us two, which is conducive to virtue, by him I shall be adored through the Sacrifice in the form of Knowledge. This is My judgement.

---

The only pre-requisite for spiritual matters is commitment (devotion) towards one's work, steadfastness in the work.